# Enlarge collapsible description

Tags: css

What I'm trying to achieve is to show more of my description as standard without clicking "show more". You can get the full description by click "show more" but I want more to be visible without having to click it. Currently the area is 123px in height, I'd like something more like 300px in height, which would give me more than 3-4 lines of text.

The site page is: http://willsperkins.myshopify.com/products/test

I'm just not sure how to do this.

```html
jQuery.themeSettings = {
   newsletter_check: "{{ settings.newsletter_check }}",
   newsletter_auto: "{{ settings.newsletter_auto }}",
   newsletter_mobile: "{{ settings.newsletter_mobile }}",
   carousel_autoplay: "{{ settings.carousel_autoplay }}",
   carousel_timer: "{{ settings.carousel_timer }}",
   collections_size: "{{ settings.collections_size }}",
   collections_border: "{{ settings.collections_border }}",
   truncated_description: "{{ settings.truncated_description }}",
   truncated_description_lines: "{{ settings.truncated_description }}",
   cart_action: "{{ settings.cart_action }}",
   gallery_max_size: "{{ settings.gallery_max_size }}",
   gallery_resizing: "{{ settings.gallery_resizing }}"
```

Comment: How is your current code breaking? From your question, it seems to be working. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: I apologise I'm fairly new to this. 


What I'm trying to achieve is to show more of my description as standard without clicking "show more". You can get the full description by click "show more" but I want more to be visible without having to click it.  Currently the area is 123px in height, I'd like something more like 300px in height, which would give me more than 3-4 lines of text.

I'm just not sure how to do this.

Comment: Could you add that to the question so people passing by will see it? People tend to skip over the comments until they want to write one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must have some thing like

```
 jQuery.themeSettings = {
        newsletter_check: "true",
        newsletter_auto: "0",
        newsletter_mobile: "false",
        carousel_autoplay: "true",
        carousel_timer: "5",
        collections_size: "small",
        collections_border: "no",
        truncated_description: "true",
        truncated_description_lines: 123,
        cart_action: "overlay",
        gallery_max_size: "false",
        gallery_resizing: "fill"
    }
```

Update this part

```
truncated_description_lines: 123,
```

to (say if you want 300px height)

```
truncated_description_lines: 300,
```

Comment: Perfect! That did exactly what I wanted. Thank-you very much.

Comment: Update your question with  jQuery.themeSettings = {.... other wise nobody will know what the issue was...and mark this answer as accepted